# C# How to await async task until it indicates to proceed

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, return

I have a C# method, which calls an external web service multiple times, in a loop. I need to call it asynchronously in a different thread.

But the caller process MUST wait until the async thread meets a certain condition, - this condition occurs much before the loop iterations complete.

Please suggest a C# code example which describes how to wait until the async block of code indicates that a certain condition has been met, so that the main process can proceed without waiting for loop to finish.

My code:

```
..
List<MyObject> objList = GetObjects();
int counter = 0;
await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    foreach (MyObject obj in objList)
    {
        counter++;
        CallExtWebSvc(obj);
        if (counter == 1)
        {
            // return an indication that main process can proceed.
        }
    }
});

// Do other stuff...
```

Comment: Please read the guide on how to ask a question. 

Your question should include: 
1, Enough code to replicate an issue.
2, input. 
3, expected output. 
4, Examples of what you have already tried.
5, specific error messages given by the compilter or runtime environment. (A stack trace can be of great service)

This is not a code writing service.

For your specific issue reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await
might help.

Comment: Hello Ajay, welcome to SO, from your question.. it seems like you have a misconcept on how async/await tasks and multi-threading works.  there has been a lot of discussion on this notion already, but I think you'll find this code review answer by Eric Lippert interesting: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/55335/86802

Answer (score 0):

You could execute your method as fire and forget and then wait for a TaskCompletionSource. This TaskCompletionSource is given to the method that calls the webservice as parameter. The method then sets a result on the TaskCompletionSource at some point.

Here is an example code piece:

```
        public async Task DoWebserviceStuffAsync(TaskCompletionSource<bool> taskCompletionSource)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                //your webservice call
                await Task.Delay(5000);

                //some condition
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    //after setting this your CallingMethod finishes 
                    //waiting the await taskCompletionSource.Task;
                    taskCompletionSource.TrySetResult(true);
                }
            }
        }

        private async Task CallerMethod()
        {
            var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

            //call method without await
            //care: You cannot catch exceptions without await
            DoWebserviceStuffAsync(taskCompletionSource);

            //wait for the DoWebserviceStuffAsync to set a result on the passed TaskCompletionSource
            await taskCompletionSource.Task;
        }
```

Comment: The async method should create the TaskCompletionSource and return the task, not have it as parameter

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the danger of "fire and forget" or you also need to wait for the full operation to complete, you could return two tasks `(Task,Task)` (C# v7 syntax). The caller would await both tasks in order.

```
public async Task Caller()
{
    var (partOne,partTwo) = DoSomethingAsync();

    await partOne;
    //part one is done...

    await partTwo;
    //part two is done...
}

public (Task,Task) DoSomethingAsync()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
    return (tcs.Task, DoWork(tcs));
}

public async Task DoWork(TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs)
{
    List<MyObject> objList = GetObjects();
    int counter = 0;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        foreach (MyObject obj in objList)
        {
            counter++;
            CallExtWebSvc(obj);
            if (counter == 1)
            {
                // return an indication that main process can proceed.
                tcs.SetResult(true);
            }
        }
    });

    // Do other stuff...
}
```

Comment: Make sure that the TaskCompletionSource is created with `TaskCompletionSource.RunContinuationsAsynchronously`. Otherwise, the continuation could be inlined when calling `tcs.SetResult`, preventing the fire-and-forget task to finish its job